# How to enable node-type based custom menu in drupal?

Tags: drupal

i'm looking for a way to display a menu block with a custom selected trail for each node-type. for example, i want all nodes of type 'story' to display the primary-link menu with the menu trail set to any specific menu item.

Comment: May you explain better what you mean? In particular it is not clear what you mean by "menu trail set ti any specific menu item". If by menu trial you mean the menu breadcrumb, then the part of the menu breadcrumb is hierarchical: in example "Home » Administer » Content management", where "home" is the home page, "Administer" is the administration page, which contains "Content Managment" (the page to administer the content of a Drupal site).

Comment: i do not mean the brecrumb, but rather the menu shown in a block, with its trail highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i actually solved my problem with custom modules...
however, i guess the right path would be the context module. since on given conditions, it can set the active menu item.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I really understand what you're asking, by maybe the [Menu Trails module](http://drupal.org/project/menutrails) could do what you want *(quoting)* :

> The module provides a means of broadly
>   categorizing nodes (by type or
>   taxonomy) as falling "under" a known
>   menu item.
>
> These nodes are not added
>   to the menu tree (keeping the menu
>   admin system sane) but they will
>   trigger the functionality above --
>   preserving navigation state for the
>   user -- when viewed.

Comment: menu trails provided me a sample of menu setting in a module. i am now  struggling my way ou of the code in order to make a site-specific module that will allow me to set my specific menu trails. thanks.